# SQLAlchemy necessary table properties

Tags: mysql, reflection, sqlalchemy, create-table

When writing SQLAlchemy models for a pre-existing database, how much information about a table do I have to give? Consider this table which is part of a MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE entities (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dn VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB, COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Based on my testing, this would be sufficient to use it:

```
class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entities'
    id          = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    dn          = Column('dn', String(100))
```

But of course its missing the UNIQUE, AUTO_INCREMENT, Engine and COLLATE information. Does SQLAlchemy care about these?

Of course I could use Reflection, but I would rather not due to consistency reasons.

Answer (score 10):

The below should produce the same result semantically, although will not produce the same query:

```
class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entities'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine':'InnoDB'}
    id          = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    dn          = Column('dn', String(100, collation='utf8_unicode_ci'), unique=True)
```

I am only not sure how to specify collation for the whole table.

Comment: You can specify the collation like this:

`__table_args__ = {
 'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 
 'mysql_charset': 'utf8',
 'mysql_collate': 'utf8_general_ci'
}`

But the question is: will sqlalchemy care? Or doesn't it matter, if the table already exists?

Comment: sqlachemy (v1.2.5) **cares** at creation: without any `__table_args__`, collattion was `latin1_swedish_ci`. With args from @GevatterGaul, I got the expected result: `utf8_general_ci`. My locales are `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__='users'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine':'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset':'utf8','mysql_collate':'utf8_czech_ci'}
    id=db.Column('iduser', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column('column_name', db.String(193))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```